# sprign kafka migration from 2.x to 3.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Hello i'm migrating from spring-boot 2 to 3 and relating to that spring-kafka from 2.x to spring-kafka 3.0.1, there were some changes and i'm struggling with one class to migrate.
I was trying with DefaultErrorHandler but there is no such method as handle.
I was using the similar public method handleRemaining, it's ok?
Then i was trying to use SeekUtils but there is no method getSkipPredicate or getRecoverStrategy that i should put as constructor paramether.
How can I migrate this class?

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DeserializationFailedErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {   

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(thrownException, records, consumer, container, this.isCommitRecovered(), this.getSkipPredicate(records, thrownException), this.logger, this.getLogLevel());
        // do somethings
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleRemaining()` is the equivalent of `handle()` in the old error handlers, but it is only called if the error handler returns true when `seeksAfterHandling()` is called by the container.

See how the `DefaultErrorHandler` calls `SeekUtils.seekOrRecover()` when it is configured that way.

However it's not clear why you need a custom error handler; deserialization exceptions can be handled by default error handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void handleRemaining(@NotNull Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, @NotNull Consumer<?, ?> consumer, @NotNull MessageListenerContainer container) {
    SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(thrownException, records, consumer, container, this.isCommitRecovered(), (c, e) -> true, this.logger, this.getLogLevel());}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).